# How to keep an editable QLabel inside paintEvent

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I want to keep an ellipse and `QLabel` in horizontal layout inside `paintEvent` and want `QLabel` should be editable on double click.

```
void CascadeColorHighlightWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    m_contRect = contentsRect().adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(176, 176, 176),1));
    painter.setBrush(QColor(255,255,255));
    painter.drawRect(m_contRect);

    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(51,51,51),1));
    QFont font( "Calibri" );
    font.setPixelSize(14);
    painter.setFont( font );

    painter.drawText(QPointF(m_contRect.x() + 18, m_contRect.y() + 28), "Color Highlight");

    int rectYPos = m_contRect.y() + 55;

    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    QRectF ellipseRect = QRectF(m_contRect.x() + 18, rectYPos, 16, 16);

    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(QColor(224,90,90));
    painter.drawEllipse(ellipseRect);

    QLabel dummy;
    dummy.setText("Density");
    dummy.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditable);

    QStyleOptionFrameV2 panel;
    panel.initFrom(&dummy);
    panel.rect = QRect(m_contRect.x() + 54, m_contRect.y() + 48, 100, 30);  // QFontMetric could provide height.
    panel.lineWidth = style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_DefaultFrameWidth, &panel, &dummy);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelLineEdit, &panel, &painter, this);

}
```

Comment: Quite cheeky to ask the same thing a third time without caring for the comments requesting more details in the previous questions, and still not providing enough information: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807146/qlineedit-in-qpainter-for-user-editing-the-text-anytime), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810564/qlineedit-not-editable-inside-painter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user point focus to QLabel image, create new QLabel object, move to appropriate window position and set text. User will see "living" editor. When user focus out remove QLabel object and repaint your image with QLabel picture.